# KML Viewer drawing issue

Tags: iphone, draw, kml

i've a problem with Aplle's example KML Viewer.
If you load a kml file with 2 points of interest at least 400km away from each other, the viewer does not draw the entire path.
Does anyone have the same problem?
Any ideas?

Comment: Try the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586579/kmlviewer-apples-example-not-working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the link provided by Anna and i solved with parsing the kml file and removing the tag

```
</coordinates></LineString><LineString><coordinates>
```