# KML Parsing and adding Overal into MKMapView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, kml, overlay-view

I'm trying to add overlay view in MKMapView using KML file, for that i downloaded a sample code from  [apple site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KMLViewer/Listings/Classes_KMLParser_m.html) its working fine in given KML file But its not working other KML files which is i downloaded from internet here is that [KML file](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CDUQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmw1.google.com%2Fcrisisresponse%2F2011%2Fjapan_earthquake_2011%2Fearthquake%2Fgoogle%2FJapan_earthquake2011_nl.kml&ei=gt7hU7C9C5G3uATpq4II&usg=AFQjCNF_mGNNsvUY3c-PmRc2Yst-faCg-A&bvm=bv.72197243,d.c2E&cad=rja). I test this KML in [display-kml.appspot.com](http://display-kml.appspot.com) its showing the right overly but in iOS Example project is not showing

I hope some one can help from here.

Thank you..

Comment: The KML file you link to doesn't contain the actual data.  It contains a link to a KMZ file which is a compressed KML file (basically a zip).  The KMLViewer sample app doesn't automatically handle loading KMZ files.  Download the KMZ, uncompress it, and use the KML file inside it with the KMLViewer.

Comment: Note the KMLViewer is just a _sample_ app -- it isn't perfect (eg. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586579/kmlviewer-apples-example-not-working) and it's not "full-featured".  You'll need to fix and enhance as needed yourself or find another ready-made KML parser.